# Novel told from the point of view of an Orc warrior in a magic world

Tags: story-identification, magic, orcs

I did not read the book, only read the first few pages or maybe a chapter. I think it came out in the last 5-10 years

I believe it was about Orcs, but might have been goblins or trolls.

A minor Orc was part of a first wave of troops going through a portal to a distant land to fight. (Setting up a beachhead)

Once he arrives he finds out that most of the troops before him have already died. I think he is able to activate a bomb/magic weapon that will kill the defending troops on the other side, (OR it does something that will deactivate the portal so the enemy can't come through) and either runs back through the portal, or is blown back through when it goes off. (pretty sure whatever it was it also closes the portal)

I believe there were also mages who were the officers who went through, who would have been returning to pass on status reports. Pretty sure this was intended to be a one-way mission for the Orcs. They were *not* supposed to be returning.

When he arrives back home to the other side and is revived, he reports what he saw and what he had done. (pretty sure the wizards were the ones who were supposed to be the ones activating the bomb/weapon/portal)

His leaders are split on what to do about it. Half want to praise him for quick thinking, and initiative, and the other half want to execute him for disobeying orders (he returned) and exceeding his authority (activating the bomb/weapon/portal) Also because the portal is closed they cant verify his story. [He is supposed to be a mindless grunt doing what they are told. Not thinking.] I think opening portals is very difficult and very random so the chance of returning to that place again is very low.

The first half wins, and I think he is promoted and given his own company of orc to lead.

That was as far as I got in the story, and as I said this was probably only the first chapter.

I think the title had "Orc" (or goblin or troll) in the title.

EDIT: Some have mentioned the Stan Nicholls series. All the ones I checked were about a motley warband of troops who were already together. The book I am looking for was focused (at least initially) on one specific Orc. (The protagonist) I don't think that series is what I am looking for, unless one of the books in that series is a prequel describing the beginnings of the leader getting assigned to the position. Also those books seem more humor oriented.

Comment: Stan Nicholls wrote a series of books with orcs as the main characters and at least some of them also feature portals. Did you check out this series?

Comment: Published in a collected edition called simply "Orcs" : https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1037549.Orcs I recall seeing this on the shelves at bookstore, but never actually read it.

Comment: Yep sounds like the Stan Nicholls one to me too, from a personal opinion standpoint one of the worst authors I ever came across (decided to go with Orcs being egg laying lizards with forked tongues in an obviously D&D inspired series of books that read like a 12 year olds efforts to diarise his favourite D&D campaign. he may have thought he was being clever & subverting expectations by making what weren't lizards in D&D lizards in his book of course but it just made him look silly), but that's just my opinion :)

Comment: I actually wondered how Stan Nicholls managed to find a publisher willing to publish Orcs for him ^ until I checked his bio & found out he was a high-up in some publishing company or other.

Comment: I did see the Stan Nicholls books in Amazon and Wikipedia when I was searching, but they did not seem to fit. And the ones I was able to check on did not start out as I described, (although i did not check all the books in the series.)

Comment: I haven't actually read this, so it's purely a guess, but could it be Mary Gentle's "Grunts"?

Comment: @user888379 Hmm I've seen that cover before, but I will have to get ahold of a copy to check it out. The few pages on the Amazon preview though did not sound familiar.

Comment: One of the Wold of Warcraft books?

Comment: @KristianH  I suppose its possible, But I played WoW for a 6 or 7 years (BC and WotLK), and don't remember that vibe from the book, and would have assumed it would have WoW on the cover. (And I dont remember anything like that on the cover.) I will try to check out some wow books and see if anything matches up.

Comment: The beginning sounds off, but maybe “Grunts!” By Mary Gentle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunts!?

Comment: No, someone else mentioned Grunts, a few comments up, I checked it out, and its not the book I was looking for.